# droid-VNC server on Nexus 7 shows noisy white screen

Tags: android, c, screenshot, vnc-server

I'm trying to run droid-VNC-server on my Nexus 7 tablet(android 4.3), but I get noisy white screen instead of captured tablet screen. When I run the same on Nexus S phone with Android 4.1.2 - it works fine. I checked this issue https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/issues/51 , but it looks like nobody maintains this product anymore. I've got exactly the same screen like appears in the issue. I'll appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to look for a solution for hours. I finally found one.

I have a nexus 7, running 4.3 and am rooted. Here's what I did.

I installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market on my android, which is Team Viewer Quick Support.

From there, I got the portable edition of Team Viewer for my PC, straight off their website. You have to scroll down to see it. If you want though, you can always install the All-in-one, that's upto you.
Link: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx

Then you just open both apps, and you connect. On your PC you will see in the top left Remote Control, you click that, and your Android device will ask for root permission. You grant it, and you should see on your PC your android screen.

There is about a half second delay, but I mean it's just what I wanted and just what I expected.

Kudos!